# regex: match pattern, but not when quoted

Tags: python-3.x, regex

How can I match the shell redirect character `>` followed by `\s+[a-z]+` but not when quoted (inside `''` or `""`) ?

```
YES: foo > bar
NO: 'foo > bar'
NO: "foo > bar"
```

Following regex matches all of the above: `(>)\s+[a-z]+`. How can I match the first line only?

I am implementing this in grc colorizer:  https://github.com/garabik/grc , which is written in python.

Comment: If you want to match the whole line, and the quotes are also at the start and at the end https://regex101.com/r/sanHOz/1

Answer (score -1):

What about this https://regex101.com/r/s5BK4T/1:

```
"[^'\"\n].*(?<!'|\")$"g
```

Here first char is checked if of `non-quote` type. And the end character is also checked if of type `non-quote` character.